# php preg_replace to remove parts of URL

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need a preg_repace function which changes this

http://www.example.org/category/page/14/no/subpage/40/some-address

To this

http://www.example.org/category/page/14/no/some-address

Where 'subpage' is constant and only the number after that is changing. It can be one, two, three or four digit number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$result = preg_replace('~subpage/[^/]+/~', '', $str);
```

or:

```
$result = preg_replace('~subpage/\d{1,4}/~', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = preg_replace('#subpage/\d+#', '', $url);
```

`\d` matches a digit, and `+` matches 1 or more of them.